# ros image_view video_recorder does not record anything

Tags: ros

I am using image_view video_recorder(http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) to record videos from a bag file. I followed this tutorial (https://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data), and decide to change the launch file to the following.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" required="true" args="/home/frankbu/bagfiles/2020-07-11-16-55-10.bag"/>
  <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="video_recorder" respawn="false" required="true" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <remap from="image" to="/camera/ceiling_image/"/>
    <param name="filename" value="ceiling.avi"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Interestingly, nothing is recorded. The topic is definitely publishing. I can visualize the video using rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/ceiling_image. But when I run the launch file, it got stuck at

```
[ INFO] [1594509115.442671189]: Waiting for topic /camera/ceiling_image...
[ INFO] [1594509115.715676818]: Starting to record MJPG video at [640 x 480]@10fps. Press Ctrl+C to stop recording.
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to pass an absolute filename for the exported file?

Comment: Yes I did that. But the recording still records nothing. 

I have two camera publishing in this bag file that have the same message type. One camera is the one that comes with Kinova Kortex, which can be recorded using this approach. The one I have trouble with is from a Logitech webcam. It seems that the webcam has lower fps, but changing that parameter has no luck either.

Comment: Whats the encoding of the images?

Comment: I am assuming it is bgr8. I changed it to rgb8 but nothing complains.

Comment: Looks like the remapping is wrong: ```<remap from="image" to="/camera/ceiling_image/"/>```. You should pass the exact topic name here. Since it ends with a ```/```, there is an error.

Comment: Oops that was a typo, I don’t have it in my actually code. Thanks for your help though! I think it is probably some encoding you mentioned earlier. I will dig up some specifications for my webcam or just use a different camera.